# Use BibTeX with Apple Pages to generate references and a bibliography

Tags: pages

I want to use BibTeX with Apple Pages for creating references to my .bib bibliography and also insert the bibliography into a Pages document. I would like to use .bst style sheets to format the bibliography.

I'm currently working with BibDesk but could change to JabRef.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your current Pages version, download CiteInPages from here...

http://jhh.med.virginia.edu/main/CiteInPages

I was able to get this to work in Pages 5.5 using CiteInPages5. It works with BibDesk. It takes a bit to install and configure it, but its a great little package. Apple really should change the name of the Pages app though. Its way too difficult to google any support for it.

EDIT: Hopefully you see this because I don't have the reputation to comment. But I guess I misunderstood your question. Its been a while since I've used CiteInPages, but I was able to get the formatting I wanted by creating a custom template. I was able to do this with some guidance from the BibDesk community mailing list. Here's a rudimentary template for the CSE style that I created.

```
<$publications>
<$pubType=article?>
<$authors><$lastName/> <$firstNames><$firstLetter/></$firstNames><?$authors>, </$authors>. <$fields.Year/>. <$fields.Title.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.stringByAppendingFullStopAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Journal.stringByRemovingTeX/>. <$fields.Volume?><$fields.Volume/><$fields.Number.parenthesizedStringIfNotEmpty/>:</$fields.Volume?><$fields.Pages.stringByConvertingDoubleHyphenToEndash/>. http://dx.doi.org/<$fields.Doi/>
</$pubType?>
<$pubType=book?>
<$authors><$lastName/> <$firstNames><$firstLetter/></$firstNames><?$authors>, </$authors>. <$fields.Year/>. <$fields.Title.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.stringByAppendingFullStopAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Edition.stringByRemovingTeX/> Edition. <$fields.Address.stringByRemovingTeX/>: <$fields.Publisher.stringByRemovingTeX/>. http://dx.doi.org/<$fields.Doi/>
</$pubType?>
<$pubType=incollection?>
<$authors><$lastName/> <$firstNames><$firstLetter/></$firstNames><?$authors>, </$authors>. <$fields.Year/>. <$fields.Title.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.stringByAppendingFullStopAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/>In: <$authors><$lastName/> <$firstNames><$firstLetter/></$firstNames><?$authors>, </$authors>, editors. <$fields.Booktitle.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.stringByAppendingFullStopAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Edition.stringByRemovingTeX.stringByAppendingFullStopAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/>ed. <$fields.Address.stringByRemovingTeX/>: <$fields.Publisher.stringByRemovingTeX/>. p. <$fields.Pages.stringByConvertingDoubleHyphenToEndash/>. http://dx.doi.org/<$fields.Doi/>
</$pubType?>

</$publications>
```

Comment: I have CiteInPages installed. But it only seems to accept custom layout files and not .bst style sheets. All I can do is use a .bst file to generate a preview in BibDesk. I don't know how to get the format into Pages.