# Make all occurrences of string superscript

Tags: pages, text, formatting

I'm currently using Pages to write a rather long essay and have run into an annoying problem I can't seem to find the answer to. I have included a bibliography in my document and have referenced the bibliography elsewhere in the essay with `[1]` where `1` is the book number I am referencing. Here is an example sentence:

> Here we see , "the quick brown fox"[1], jumps over the "Lazy dog"[2].

My intention is to format the sentence like this:

> Here we see , "the quick brown fox"<sup>[1]</sup> , jumps over the "Lazy dog"<sup>[2]</sup>.

Whilst I understand you can select the text, click Format, Font, Baseline and select Superscript; this would take an extremely long time to do as there are around 100 places where I would need to do this.

Is there a way to find and replace a string, e.g. [1] with <sup>[1]</sup>, throughout the whole document?

Comment: Relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/174911/24324

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would search for online superscript converter to convert that word 1 to ¹ such as https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator

Then I would copy converted text :

1. Open Pages
2. Look for (find) "[1]"
3. Change "Find" to "Find & Replace"
4. Paste the copied text in the replace field "[¹]"
5. Click on "Replace all"

[image: screenshot of the 'Find & Replace' dialog]

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this doesn't change the format as such but makes use of Unicode superscript characters. These may or may not be available in the font the OP uses.